# OpenAM - How to get state of previous login module in authentication chain

Tags: java, authentication, openam, chain

I'm working with OpenAM and I need to chain two login modules as following:

```
1. WindowsDesktopSSO as OPTIONAL
2. CustomLoginModule as SUFFICIENT
```

The idea is to authenticate with WindowsDesktopSSO if possible and fall back on a CustomLoginModule wether WindowsDesktopSSO succeed or fails.

The CustomLoginModule is a module of my own. It is correctly called after WindowsDesktopSSO success and failure. The problem is that I cannot find how to know about WindowsDesktopSSO authentication status : how can I know if first authentication module in chain succeeded or failed ?

I tried working with sharedStates, but WindowsDesktopSSO doesn't populates the sharedStates. The `super.getLoginState()` and `super.getCurrentState()` methods do not help either.

Do you know how I can get the state of previous module in authentication chain ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two API calls that may be of help:

```
getLoginState("mymodule").getFailureModuleSet()
```

and

```
getLoginState("mymodule").getSuccessModuleSet()
```

However they are both package private, so they can't really be accessed from an authentication module.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! The `getFailureModuleSet()` method indicates name of missed modules, which is very helpful. But unfortunately the `getSuccessModuleSet()` method is not reachable since it is protected.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Either you will need to use reflection, or customize the wdsso auth module so that it saves the module outcome in the sharedState.